# Uninitialized constant Game::World when I try and initialize the World class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to create a basic text adventure in ruby, and I'm roughly following a tutorial (https://jsrn.gitbooks.io/make-your-first-text-adventure-in-ruby/content/creating_the_framework.html)

But when I try and run my code I get this error:

```
GameBase.rb:10:in `initialize': uninitialized constant Game::World (NameError)
    from GameBase.rb:55:in `new'
    from GameBase.rb:55:in `<main>'
```

This is my code:

### From GameBase.rb

```
Dir["GameDir/**.*"].each { |file| require_relative file }

class Game
  Actions = [
:forward, :backward, :look, :attack, :loot, :inventory, :use, :cast
  ]

  def initialize
@world = World.new
@player = Player.new

start_game
  end

  private
  def start_game
while @player.alive?
  @current_room = @world.get_room_of(@player)

  print_player_status

  action = take_player_input
  next unless ACTIONS.include? action

  take_action(action)
end
  end

  def take_player_input
print "What do you do?"
gets.chomp.to_sym
  end

  def take_action(action)
case action
  when :forward
    @world
  when :backward
    @world
  when :look
    @world
  when :attack
    @current_room.interact(@player)
  when :loot
    @current_room.interact(@player)
  when :inventory
  when :use
  when :cast
  end
end
  end

  Game.new
```

### And from world.rb

```
class World

  def initialize
    @past_rooms = 0
    @current_room = 0
  end

  def move_entity_forward(entity)
    @current_room += 1
  end

  def move_entity_backward(entity)
    @current_room -= 1
  end

  def get_room_of(entity)
    if @current_room <= @past_rooms then @current_room
    else
      Room.new
      @past_rooms += 1 end
  end
end

  class Room
  attr_accessor :size, :content

  def initialize
    @content    = get_content
    @size       = get_size
    @adjetive   = get_adjetive
  end

  def interact(player)
    if @content
      @content.interact(player)
      @content = nil
    else
      puts "There isn't anything here..."
    end
  end

  private
  def get_content
    [Monster, Item.sample.new]
  end

  def get_size
    dimensions = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100, 200]
    "#{dimensions.sample}'x#{dimensions.sample}'"
  end

  def get_adjetive
    ["well-lit", "dim", "filthy", "suprisingly clean", "round", "muddy", "oppressive"]
  end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the top of `GameBase.rb`:

```
require_relative 'world'
```

This tells the Ruby interpreter to look for a file named `world.rb` in the same folder as `GameBase.rb` and run the code in that file, which would define the `World` class.  Then the `World` class would be available when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ran into the same problem because I didn't see instructions in the tutorial that the extra files (world.rb, player.rb, etc.) are expected to be in a subfolder. I had them all in the same folder, game.rb , which was causing this error.

The first line of code in game.rb is telling Ruby where to load all the related game files

```
Dir["GameDir/**.*"]
```

So, if your game.rb file is in a directory 'game' for example, then all the related files need to be in a directory game>GameDir since you are telling it to look in the GameDir folder.